# WPF ListView like in Excel 2010 -> File->Recent-> Recent Workbooks

Tags: wpf, listview

I'd like to have a ListView functioning similarly that is found for example in Excel 2010 (when you go to File -> Recent -> Recent Workbooks).

In short, I need help for:

- **Define custom item highlight color when mouse is over the item** (The default blueish color is not suitable for me)
- **Clicking any item on the  list executes a command <del>rather than selects the item</del>**
  <del>(so it should not be possible to select any item, only click it)</del>

On top of those (I managed to do myself):

- headers should be hidden
  (I have defined ColumnHeaderContainerStyle to make headers collapsed) and;
- ListViewItem template should be customized
  (I have defined GridViewColumn.CellTemplate for that)

Comment: `"so it should not be possible to select any item, only click it"` is clicking not selecting? so if the mouse is over the item show the higlight, but if you click it dont show the highlight?

Comment: Ok, that was actually poor definition from me. Clicking=selecting, so item can get selected but I need the selected item highlight color to be exactly the same as mouse over highlight color. Also, when any item gets selected, I need the item's command binding execute immediately.